# Subtypes and assignment compatibility in Typescript when S extends T

Tags: typescript

Quoting the [Assignment compatibility](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.11.4)
and [Subtypes and Supertypes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.11.3) from the Typescript spec:

> S is **assignable** to a type T, and T is **assignable from** S, if S has no excess properties with respect to T ([3.11.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.11.5)) and one of the following is true:
>
> ...
>
> S is an object type, an intersection type, an enum type, or the Number, Boolean, or String primitive type, T is an object type, and for each member M in T, one of the following is true:
>
> ...

According to this definition, `S` is allowed to be `Number`,`Boolean` or `String` and `T` to be an object type. So that means, I could do this: `const A: {test: string} = 5`. Here, `T` is `{test:string}` and `S` is `number`. I know I can't do this, but according to the my interpretation of the spec, this should be valid. What is the reasoning behind that definition in the spec?

Comment: You haven't drilled down into the "one of the following is true" of each member `M` of `{test: string}`.  The rest of that goes on to say that if `M` is a property then `S` has to have an apparent property of the same name... but `number` has no `test` property, so it fails.

Comment: @jcalz I've read and I understand that part too, but I still didn't understand the logic behind claiming that S can be `number`, `boolean` or `string` type, but now I realized from your comment that if I have `toString` function property for example, then I can assign a number to `A` because `number` has `toString` function property. Thank you for the clarification.